# EC2 ecs cluster , ALB and service discovery (with awsvpc mode and with bridge mode in task definition)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

Does ECS with EC2 machines can use service discovery?
The AWS documentation says all about Fargate,
have anyone done it with ALB, EC2 ECS cluster, service discovery.

Answer (score 1):

ECS uses [AWS Cloud Map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/latest/dg/what-is-cloud-map.html) for service discovery. You can use the AWS Cloud Map for other services as well:

> You can also use AWS Cloud Map to register and locate **any cloud resources**, such as Amazon EC2 instances, Amazon DynamoDB tables, Amazon S3 buckets, Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) queues, or APIs deployed on top of Amazon API Gateway, among others.